# Create users from form

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

The title pretty much says it..

1) I need to create a google form.

Name: Will

Last Name: Smith

Email: will_smith@gmail.com

2) Put the form in a google site where some guy will fill it up.

3) Then with the content I need to automatically create a user as I'd do it in the Google Admin Console.

The guy who fills up the form doesn't have access to the Google Admin Console and I need this process to be automatic.

Is there an easier way to do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a google form like the Google's Documentation
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/87809?hl=en